# Getting the time as file name

Tags: c++, c, directshow

I have a program that grabs a video using Direct-show. My problem is that I want the saved video to have the time as name. Here is what I 've done :

```
CoInitialize(NULL);
CComPtr<IGraphBuilder> graph;
graph.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph);
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
time (&rawtime);
timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
wchar_t pathstuff[50];
swprintf(pathstuff, L"D:\\BMDvideos\\%hs.avi", asctime(timeinfo));
LPCOLESTR x = pathstuff;
HRESULT hr = BuilGraph(graph,x);
..........
```

This doesn't work, any idea how can I get this done?

Comment: Have you checked, if your `timeinfo*` contains valid data?

Comment: @bash.d A more likely problem is that he's under Windows.  `asctime` uses colons in its formatting, and Windows doesn't allow colons in filenames (except for special purposes, like the initial device specifier or secondary streams).

Comment: `asctime` has spaces and a newline in its output. This could be one of the problems.

Comment: You're trying to solve three problems - getting the time, formatting a filename, writing a file. Break it down to make sure each works independently.

Comment: In addition, I don't think Engine is operating with LPCOLESTRs (BSTRs) correctly.

Comment: @OlafDietsche One might think so.  However: I'm not sure about the newline, but Windows definitely accepts spaces.  (I'd avoid them, however, because they will confuse so many useful tools.)  On the other hand, `asctime` definitely does contain colons, which Windows _doesn't_ accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function for formatting time is `strftime`, so you could do
something like:

```
char filename[1000];
size_t l = strftime( filename,
                     sizeof(filename),
                     "D:/BMDvideos/%Y-%m-%dT%Hh%Mm%S.avi",
                     timeinfo );
assert( l != 0 );
```

Several comments:

- You do *not* want wide character filenames.  They're not
  standard, and not widely supported.  (The universal standard for
  Unicode filenames is UTF-8, which does work everywhere.  In
  fact, you do not want wide characters anywhere outside your
  program.)
- You can't use any standard formatting functions, like
  `asctime`, as they will almost certainly use colons (`':'`) in
  the time format, and colons are illegal characters in a filename
  under Windows.  You must specify the exact format yourself,
  using `strftime`.
- There are probably a lot of other characters you should avoid
  as well.  I tend to limit my filenames to alphanumerics,
  underscore, hyphen and dot, and I'm not that sure concerning the
  portability of hyphen, or a name with more than one dot.  If the
  names are not for human consumption, I'd just use
  `"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`, with no separators.
- Finally, it's useful to use the ISO ordering (year, month,
  day) for dates, as this means lexicographical sorting
  corresponds to a sort on the dates.

EDIT:

Since you say that you *must* use `wchar_t` filenames (which is
a very bad policy): you can still use the above to generate the
filename, then convert it to `std::wstring` by simply using
`std::wstring( filename, filename + strlen( filename ) )`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it work but, I still need wide character filename

Comment: @Engine Why?  Windows will accept both on a local disk, but if you ever want to backup (perhaps over NFS), or do anything else which may result in the files being seen by a non-Windows system, you're going to be in trouble.  (This works both ways: I've had problems with filenames containing colons, generated under Linux, which caused no end of problems when the filesystem was mounted on a Windows box.)  Still, if you must: just copy the generated string to a `std::wstring` (using the two iterator constructor).  If the filename is pure ASCII, this will work.

Answer (score 1):

asctime adds *'\n'* character at the end of returned string which is not valid for a file name

> The call ctime(t) is equivalent to asctime(localtime(t)).  It
>   converts the calendar time t into a null-terminated  string  of  the
>          form
>
> ```
>           "Wed Jun 30 21:49:08 1993\n"
> ```

try using strftime isntead

```
char name[100]
strftime(name, 100, "%F_%R", timeinfo);
```

Comment: Do _not_ use `"%R"`.  This will insert colons, which aren't legal characters in a filename under Windows.

Answer (score 1):

`wchar_t *` and `LPCOLESTR` aren't compatible types, at runtime. Have you read [this BSTR manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? It'll tell you how to allocate your BSTRs correctly.